# Some strangeness with agda-mode for Agda 2.5.1

Tags: emacs, agda, agda-mode

So like other Agda enthusiasts, with the release of the new version of Agda, I quickly cabal-force-installed the latest and greatest. However, after compiling and setting-up agda-mode (the new one), my emacs is giving me some strange settings.

I no longer have an `include dirs` menu when I attempt to customize agda, I've circumvented this by using the `program args` menu and adding `--include-dir=<stuff>`. However, the colour scheme is bothersome. In a literate agda file, everything outside of `\begin{code}` and `\end{code}` is coloured salmon-red and I want it to be black as was in older versions.

I've played around with the highlight settings, but just could not get this to change. Any advice would be most appreciated!

Thank-you!

**Edit** : the removal of the include-dirs is no error, the [change log](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Agda-2.5.1/changelog) under the emacs section mentions this and more.